# Dynamically fill Sencha Touch picker

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm using Sencha Touch in one of my mobile projects. As one of the components of it I'm using the Picker. I know that the picker values are being got from the "data" attribute which is an array containing object like so:

```
[{"text":"One","value":1},{"text":"Two","value":2},{"text":"Three","value":3}]
```

However what I need to do is - fill the picker with values from an array which is being generated dynamically from a store. Could anybody help me with this, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Ext.Picker.Slot](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.picker.Slot) which allows you to add a Ext.data.Store to it. The store will enable you to get data from server and the Picker slots will be populated.

This is what given in Sencha docs:

```
A general picker class. Ext.picker.Slots are used to organize multiple 
scrollable slots into a single picker. slots is the only necessary configuration.

The slots configuration with a few key values:

name: The name of the slot (will be the key when using 
getValues in this Ext.picker.Picker)
title: The title of this slot (if useTitles is set to true)
data/store: The data or store to use for this slot.
Remember, Ext.picker.Slot class extends from Ext.dataview.DataView.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{   
    xtype:'picker',
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%',
    id:'chooseLocationRoomListPicker',
    baseCls:'pickerCls',
    cancelButton: false,
    doneButton: false,
    toolbar:false,
    slots : [{
             name:'chooseLocationRoomListPickerList',
             store: Ext.getStore('roomStore'),
             displayField: 'level',
             valueField: 'id',
             align:'center',
             value:'202'
    }]
}
```